# Locating CSS selector for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get selenium to input a store location. Here is my current code:

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from time import sleep

#load page 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.samsclub.com/c/grocery/1444?xid=hdr:shop:grocery")

#zipcode
clubname = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "bst-btn.bst-btn-small.bst-btn-ghost.sc-chevron-button.flyout-trigger.blue-steel-button")
clubname.click()

link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "find other clubs")
link.click()

zip = driver.find_element(By.ID,"inputbox11")
zip.clear()
zip.click()
zip.send_keys("68023") #enter zip
zip.submit()

make_this_store = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Make this your club")
make_this_store.click()
```

However, the output says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".bst-btn.bst-btn-small.bst-btn-ghost.sc-chevron-button.flyout-trigger.blue-steel-button"}
```

Any guidance on fixing this error would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the html in your question.

Comment: `bst-btn.bst-btn-small.bst-btn-ghost.sc-chevron-button.flyout-trigger.blue-steel-button` I can't find anything with this locator in the launched page. Hence `NoSuchElement` execption. Can you point at the web element you want to click?

Comment: I'm trying to click on the drop down on the top left next to "your club"